# One-round feistel network (DES) attack

Tags: des, attack, feistel-network

I can't find out how to break 1 round of feistel network (obtaining the key).

[image]

I understand why this equation takes place:

$R_1 \oplus L_0 = f(R_0, k_1)$

**EDIT**: The function f looks like this:
[image]

But how can i find the key ($k_1$) from it?

I saw it's possible in a few references:

http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~cs236506/04/slides/crypto-slides-05-bc-tutor.4x2.pdf
http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~maheshwa/courses/4109/Seminar11/atttack%20on%20DES.pdf
https://www.icg.isy.liu.se/courses/tsit03/forelasningar/cryptolecture04.pdf
[KPA on Feistel cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20934/kpa-on-feistel-cipher/20985#20985)

Thanks!

Comment: did you try the brute force?

Comment: There are several definitions of breaking a cipher. Obtaining the key is only one, and often is inappropriate. Others include ability to decipher any ciphertext, breaking indistinguishability of ciphertext from random for chosen plaintext..

Comment: In general you cannot. Let f be a constant function then the output is independent of the key. So you need to make assumptions about the function f if you want to extract the key.

Comment: @kelalaka - you can always brute force, im looking for a smart solution.
fgrieu - as i said, i want a smart way to obtain the key
Maeher - i know there is a solution :)

Comment: your question is fully answered in Biham's slides.

Comment: @kodlu - no it is not, there is no explanation there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$X' = F(X, k) = P(S(E(X) \oplus k ))$$

the value of key $K$ is an element of the set

$$ \{V \oplus E(R_0): V \in S^{-1}(P^{-1}(Z)) \}$$

where

$$Z = R_1 \oplus L_0$$

and

$$
S^{-1}(P^{-1}(Z)) 
$$
is the set of possible inverse images of the parallel map of the Sboxes $S$ which is not one to one.

Total number of possible keys is $2^{16}$ because Sboxes are not bijective, there are $4$ possible inputs leading to same output.

Comment: Do you have some particular reason for assuming that the OP's function $f$ would be of this form?

Comment: S, E and P are known to the attacker? only the key is secret?

Comment: @khan - if what you are saying is true, we can break a 16 rounds des also. according to the references that i mentioned in my edit, the number of possibilities is 2^16

Comment: no you cant, because normally you know plaintext and ciphertext, not the intermediate states after every single round so you can not break 16 rounds of DES this way.

Comment: @khan - if im getting you right, it's because if i have L16 and R16 i can't find K16 because i don't know R15 and L15?

Comment: yes. All you know is L0, R0, L16 and R16, and you cant move forward way from L0 and R0 to L15 and R15 without the knowledge of roundkeys k1 to k15.

Comment: @user3343396 updated the answer to the edited question.

Comment: Z=X' in your solution right? X'=L0 xor R1

Comment: yes. both represent same value if X is R0 as input to function F

Comment: great thanks! i thought it will be more complicated XD

Comment: @khan - in second thought, i think your answer is not accurate. in order to calculate the opposite function of S there are 4 possibilities for each portion (6 bit) in the key (8 portions), so we need to try 4^8=2^16 possibilities to find the correct key.

Comment: I edited to clarify the answer. @khan, please fix if inaccurate.

Comment: @user3343396 yes, there are more than one possible keys for this because sbox is not bijective. the exact count is 2^16